# PMS TO TPX Number

Tags: pantone

Please refer the below Pantone
**Pantone PMS282 C
Pantone PMS2727 C**
I want to covert this to in TPX or TPG , Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can cross reference Pantone colours with TCX or TPG colours by using the [Pantone Connect](https://connect.pantone.com/) service. You can sign up for a free account and see/search the colours. However, the cross referencing functionality requires a paid account unfortunately.

If you don't need complete accuracy, it might be possible to add a Pantone colour to your palette in the free version of Pantone Connect, and then add a TCX/TPG colour which is visually close, and compare the two.  There's probably not an exact 1:1 colour match anyway, even if you do use the paid cross referencing functionality, so eyeballing it might be sufficient for you.

Another method is if you have access to a Pantone solid colour guide book and TCX colour samples, you could try matching the samples visually.

Note: I have no affiliation with Pantone or the Pantone Connect website.